# Unable to launch Edna & Harvey: The Breakout on Mac OS X via Steam - Wineskin

Tags: steam, macos, windows, wine, edna-and-harvey-breakout

I'm new here and I got no clue about PC/Mac/Games/how to ask questions in here in general so I need some help. (I've already looked through previous questions but nothing could help me...)

I wanted to play 'Edna & Harvey: The Breakout', so I bought it on steam and because there is only a PC version available and I have an iMac (OS X Yosemite v.10.10.5), I needed to find a solution to run this game and therefor steam for Windows on Mac (that much I know).

I followed [those](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNrUiLXqdJk) instructions and it worked very well - I installed steam for Windows and downloaded and installed the game. But when I try to launch the game this error text appears:

[image]

It seams that the error message disappears after a while, so I get no error, the game just won't start. Everytime I try to start the game it says "first installation" (Java runtime enviroment, Microsoft .NET Framework and something else, I can't read that fast) - so maybe the game isn't installed yet.

**So what exactly is my problem and how can I fix it so I can finally play this awesome game again?**

Comment: Link to instructions broken. Also, what Java version do you use?

Comment: I use Java v.8 Update 65 - that's what I found. Does that help?

Comment: I don't have the game, and don't know how wine setup works - however http://steamcommunity.com/app/255320/discussions/0/620712999974404322 suggests that this game does not like Java 8. Try to uninstall it, install most recent Java7 and try again.

Comment: Additionally - did you try installing it natively without wine? Does Steam forbid it? I don't have all the details, but all the info suggests that this game is a Java application, which shouldn't care about the OS.

Comment: @Deltharis " I bought it on steam and because there is only a PC version available"

Comment: @ardaozkal There is no such thing as a "PC version" of a java application, it runs on a Virtual Machine. I don't know how Steam handles such restrictions, but if it allows to download the game regardless it might (or even should, as cross-platfom compatibility is one of the things Java proudly boasts) work.

Comment: It still doesn't work with Java 7

Comment: And I can't download it on steam for mac, so I can't try to install the game. And I can't find the folder where steam for windows saved the exe. or whatever to try it manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really an answer but there is **no way** to launch "Edna & Harvey: The Breakout" on Mac OSX via steam or CD with Wineskin or any other program for that matter. It's just not possible.

That's the answer I got from the support team of Daedalic, the developers of the game.

For all the apple users: there is a however a version for iPad that works just fine.